# Do not allow appointments before current time

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress XtraScheduler and I need to deny the creation/modification of appointments (using the edit form or the drag and drop method) before the current time. Someone can help me to acomplish this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you check on the `ASPxScheduler.AppointmentsInserted` event and then pop up a dialog based on the appointment's properties?  If you have to, then there should be a `Delete` method (of some description) to remove the appointment.  I dare say that the `EventArgs` for the event contain all of the `Appointments` that have been added.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, [here's the documentation I just searched for](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3810).

Comment: Thanks for the comments Paul. I am using winForms and check the docs for that but I can't get it. I need some example code to guide me but I don't find anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I would think that you need to be looking at [this page](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2334), and utilising the properties and methods here.

After looking through the page I came across [this event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraSchedulerSchedulerStorageBase_AppointmentInsertingtopic) which seems to do pretty much what you want. The code on this page shows you how to cancel an insertion if its date falls before a requied date.